# Matlab Guide - Display additional informations on a video

Tags: matlab, video, plot, matlab-guide

I am displaying a video of a mouse in an U.I and I have a file with the coordinates of its head through time. I would like to display for each frame the position of the head using a marker for example.

Here is what I actually do :

```
    % --- Get the current frame, display it and set axes properties
    setDirectory(handles.video,handles.numFrame);
    I = handles.video.read();        
    imagesc(I,'Parent',handles.axes1);
    hold on
    plot(handles.xHead(handles.numFrame),handles.yHead(handles.numFrame),...
           'o','MarkerFaceColor','b','MarkerSize',10,'Parent',handles.axes1);
    colormap(gray);
    handles.axes1.Visible = 'off';
    drawnow
    hold off
```

And the problem is that it only display the video and when I pause the processus (with a callback button) it display only the point without the current frame...

I looked around but found nothing. Any help would be appreciate :)

Thank you !

edit :

here is the code of the button pause_callback :

```
% --- Executes on button press in play.
function play_Callback(hObject, ~, handles)
% hObject    handle to play (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% --- Inverse the value of the button Play/Pause when it is clicked
if strcmp(hObject.String,'Play')
    hObject.String = 'Pause';
else
    hObject.String = 'Play';
end

% --- Algorithm to read the video and graphics
while strcmp(hObject.String,'Pause')
    % --- Get the way of reading of the video
    handles.sens = get(handles.listbox3, 'Value');
if handles.sens == 1
    % Go forward
    handles.defilement = 1;
elseif handles.sens == 2
    % Go back
    handles.defilement = -1;
end

% --- Get the speed of the video
tPause = get(handles.edit2,'String');
tPause = str2num(tPause);
if isempty(tPause)
    set(handles.edit2,'String','1');
    warndlg('Vous devez entrer une valeur num�rique non nulle !');
elseif tPause ~= handles.speedBase
    handles.speedBase = tPause;
end

% --- Check if there is still a frame in the video
if handles.numFrame > 0 && handles.numFrame < (handles.nbrFrames + 1)

    % --- Get the current frame, display it and set axes properties
    setDirectory(handles.video,handles.numFrame);
    I = handles.video.read();        
    imagesc(I,'Parent',handles.axes1);
    colormap(gray);
    handles.axes1.Visible = 'off';
    pause(0.001); 

    % --- Assign the new position of the marker 
    handles.xMV = handles.numFrame;
    handles.yMV = handles.yGV(handles.xMV);

    handles.xMR = handles.numFrame;
    handles.yMR = handles.yGR(handles.xMR);

    handles.xMRat = handles.numFrame;
    handles.yMRat = handles.yGRat(handles.xMRat);

    if handles.angle.Value==1
        handles.xMAng = handles.numFrame;
        handles.yMAng = handles.yGAng(handles.xMAng);
    end

    % --- Assign the new scale for Y
    if mod(handles.numFrame,(handles.ecart/10)) == 0 && handles.autoscale.Value == 1
        [handles.YminV, handles.YmaxV] = autoscale(handles.yGVsmooth,handles.ecart,handles.numFrame,handles.nbrFrames);
        handles.yminV.String = handles.YminV;
        handles.ymaxV.String = handles.YmaxV;

        [handles.YminR, handles.YmaxR] = autoscale(handles.yGRsmooth,handles.ecart,handles.numFrame,handles.nbrFrames);
        handles.yminR.String = handles.YminR;
        handles.ymaxR.String = handles.YmaxR;

        [handles.YminRat, handles.YmaxRat] = autoscale(handles.yGRat,handles.ecart,handles.numFrame,handles.nbrFrames);
        handles.yminRat.String = handles.YminRat;
        handles.ymaxRat.String = handles.YmaxRat;

        if handles.angle.Value==1
            [handles.YminAng, handles.YmaxAng] = autoscale(handles.yGAng,handles.ecart,handles.numFrame,handles.nbrFrames);
            handles.yminAng.String = handles.YminAng;
            handles.ymaxAng.String = handles.YmaxAng;
            disp(handles.YminAng);
            disp(handles.YmaxAng);
        end
    end

    % --- Refresh graphics
    if handles.numFrame < handles.ecart
        % --- Display the graphics
        % Graph of red fluorescence
        plot(handles.xGV(1:(handles.ecart*2)),handles.yGV(1:(handles.ecart*2)),...
            handles.xMV,handles.yMV,'o','MarkerFaceColor','r','MarkerSize',3, ...
            'Color','g','Parent',handles.axes2);
        % Graph of green fluorescence
        plot(handles.xGR(1:(handles.ecart*2)),handles.yGR(1:(handles.ecart*2)),...
            handles.xMR,handles.yMR,'o','MarkerFaceColor','g','MarkerSize',3, ...
            'Color','r','Parent',handles.axes3);
        % Graph of ratio
        plot(handles.xGRat(1:(handles.ecart*2)),handles.yGRat(1:(handles.ecart*2)),...
            handles.xMRat,handles.yMRat,'o','MarkerFaceColor','g','MarkerSize',3, ...
            'Color','b','Parent',handles.axes4);
        % Graph of the angle
        if handles.angle.Value==1
            plot(handles.xGAng(1:(handles.ecart*2)),handles.yGAng(1:(handles.ecart*2)),...
                handles.xMAng,handles.yMAng,'o','MarkerFaceColor','g','MarkerSize',3, ...
                'Color','y','Parent',handles.axes6);
            set(handles.axes6,'xLim',[1 (handles.ecart*2)],'yLim',[handles.YminAng handles.YmaxAng]);
            set(handles.axes6.Title,'String','Angle');
        end
        % --- Set the properties of the axis
        % Graph of red fluorescence
        set(handles.axes2,'xLim',[1 (handles.ecart*2)],'yLim',[handles.YminV handles.YmaxV]);
        set(handles.axes2.Title,'String','Fluorescence Verte');
        % Graph of green fluorescence
        set(handles.axes3,'xLim',[1 (handles.ecart*2)],'yLim',[handles.YminR handles.YmaxR]);
        set(handles.axes3.Title,'String','Fluorescence Rouge');
        % Graph of ratio
        set(handles.axes4,'xLim',[1 (handles.ecart*2)],'yLim',[handles.YminRat handles.YmaxRat]);
        set(handles.axes4.Title,'String','Ratio');

    elseif handles.numFrame > handles.ecart && handles.numFrame < (handles.nbrFrames - handles.ecart-1)
        % --- Display the graph and the marker and make the graph dynamic
        % Graph of red fluorescence
        plot(handles.xGV((handles.numFrame-handles.ecart):(handles.numFrame+handles.ecart)), ...
            handles.yGV((handles.numFrame-handles.ecart):(handles.numFrame+handles.ecart)),...
            handles.xMV,handles.yMV,'o','MarkerFaceColor','r','MarkerSize',3, ...
            'Color','g','Parent',handles.axes2);
        % Graph of green fluorescence
        plot(handles.xGR((handles.numFrame-handles.ecart):(handles.numFrame+handles.ecart)), ...
            handles.yGR((handles.numFrame-handles.ecart):(handles.numFrame+handles.ecart)),...
            handles.xMR,handles.yMR,'o','MarkerFaceColor','g','MarkerSize',3, ...
            'Color','r','Parent',handles.axes3);
        % Graph of ratio
        plot(handles.xGRat((handles.numFrame-handles.ecart):(handles.numFrame+handles.ecart)), ...
            handles.yGRat((handles.numFrame-handles.ecart):(handles.numFrame+handles.ecart)),...
            handles.xMRat,handles.yMRat,'o','MarkerFaceColor','g','MarkerSize',3, ...
            'Color','b','Parent',handles.axes4);
        if handles.angle.Value==1
            plot(handles.xGAng((handles.numFrame-handles.ecart):(handles.numFrame+handles.ecart)), ...
                handles.yGAng((handles.numFrame-handles.ecart):(handles.numFrame+handles.ecart)),...
                handles.xMAng,handles.yMAng,'o','MarkerFaceColor','g','MarkerSize',3, ...
                'Color','b','Parent',handles.axes6);
            set(handles.axes6,'xLim',[(handles.numFrame-handles.ecart) (handles.numFrame+handles.ecart-1)],...
                'yLim',[handles.YminAng handles.YmaxAng]);
            set(handles.axes6.Title,'String','Angle');
        end
        % --- Set the properties of the axis
        % Graph of red fluorescence
        set(handles.axes2,'xLim',[(handles.numFrame-handles.ecart) (handles.numFrame+handles.ecart-1)],...
            'yLim',[handles.YminV handles.YmaxV]);
        set(handles.axes2.Title,'String','Fluorescence Verte');
        % Graph of green fluorescence
        set(handles.axes3,'xLim',[(handles.numFrame-handles.ecart) (handles.numFrame+handles.ecart-1)],...
            'yLim',[handles.YminR handles.YmaxR]);
        set(handles.axes3.Title,'String','Fluorescence Rouge');
        % Graph of ratio
        set(handles.axes4,'xLim',[(handles.numFrame-handles.ecart) (handles.numFrame+handles.ecart-1)],...
            'yLim',[handles.YminRat handles.YmaxRat]);
        set(handles.axes4.Title,'String','Ratio');
    elseif handles.numFrame > (handles.nbrFrames - handles.ecart)
        % --- Display the graph and the marker
        % Graph of red fluorescence
        plot(handles.xGV((handles.nbrFrames-(handles.ecart*2)):handles.nbrFrames-1), ...
            handles.yGV((handles.nbrFrames-(handles.ecart*2)):handles.nbrFrames-1),...
            handles.xMV,handles.yMV,'o','MarkerFaceColor','r','MarkerSize',3, ...
            'Color','g','Parent',handles.axes2);
        % Graph of green fluorescence
        plot(handles.xGR((handles.nbrFrames-(handles.ecart*2)):handles.nbrFrames-1), ...
            handles.yGR((handles.nbrFrames-(handles.ecart*2)):handles.nbrFrames-1),...
            handles.xMR,handles.yMR,'o','MarkerFaceColor','g','MarkerSize',3, ...
            'Color','r','Parent',handles.axes3);
        % Graph of ratio
        plot(handles.xGRat((handles.nbrFrames-(handles.ecart*2)):handles.nbrFrames-1), ...
            handles.yGRat((handles.nbrFrames-(handles.ecart*2)):handles.nbrFrames-1),...
            handles.xMRat,handles.yMRat,'o','MarkerFaceColor','g','MarkerSize',3, ...
            'Color','b','Parent',handles.axes4);
        if handles.angle.Value==1
            plot(handles.xGAng((handles.nbrFrames-(handles.ecart*2)):handles.nbrFrames-1), ...
                handles.yGAng((handles.nbrFrames-(handles.ecart*2)):handles.nbrFrames-1),...
                handles.xMAng,handles.yMAng,'o','MarkerFaceColor','g','MarkerSize',3, ...
                'Color','b','Parent',handles.axes6);
            set(handles.axes6,'xLim',[((handles.nbrFrames-1)-(handles.ecart*2)) handles.nbrFrames],...
                'yLim',[handles.YminAng handles.YmaxAng]);
            set(handles.axes6.Title,'String','Angle');
        end
        % --- Set the properties of the axis
        % Graph of red fluorescence
        set(handles.axes2,'xLim',[((handles.nbrFrames-1)-(handles.ecart*2)) handles.nbrFrames],...
            'yLim',[handles.YminV handles.YmaxV]);
        set(handles.axes2.Title,'String','Fluorescence Verte');
        % Graph of green fluoresence
        set(handles.axes3,'xLim',[((handles.nbrFrames-1)-(handles.ecart*2)) handles.nbrFrames],...
            'yLim',[handles.YminR handles.YmaxR]);
        set(handles.axes3.Title,'String','Fluorescence Rouge');
        % Graph of ratio
        set(handles.axes4,'xLim',[((handles.nbrFrames-1)-(handles.ecart*2)) handles.nbrFrames],...
            'yLim',[handles.YminRat handles.YmaxRat]);
        set(handles.axes4.Title,'String','Ratio');
    end  

    % --- Manage the speed of the video
    pause(tPause);

    % --- Conditions whiwh prevent to assign a wrong value to
    % --- handles.numFrame
    if handles.numFrame == 1 && handles.sens == 1
        handles.numFrame = handles.numFrame + handles.defilement;
    elseif handles.numFrame > 1 && handles.numFrame < handles.nbrFrames
        handles.numFrame = handles.numFrame + handles.defilement;
    elseif handles.numFrame == handles.nbrFrames && handles.sens == 2
        handles.numFrame = handles.numFrame + handles.defilement;
    end
end
    % --- Refresh the UI
    set(handles.text14,'String',handles.numFrame);

% --- Manage the case we went back to the beginning 
if handles.numFrame == 1 && handles.sens == 2
    if strcmp(hObject.String,'Pause')
        % reset status of the button
        hObject.String = 'Play';
    end
    break
end

% --- Manage the case we arrived to the end of the video
if handles.numFrame == handles.nbrFrames
    if strcmp(hObject.String,'Pause')
        % reset status of the button
        hObject.String = 'Play';
    end
    break
end
end

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject,handles);
```

I beg you pardon for the bad indentation but I don't know how to solve it quickly in stack overflow.

Comment: Can you show your pause callback?

Comment: I edited my post !

Answer (score 0):

This problem has to do with how matlab uses event queues and how drawnow effects those queues. I would try

drawnow expose

This should immediately update graphics without allowing other callbacks already in the event queue to process before updating.

Comment: It doesn't work... If I do drawnow expose it only display the point of the position and no more the image ! 
Thank you to try helping me.